# Angular calendar | Need a default scroll view to 8AM- 11PM in Day/Week With a fixed Header

Tags: angular-calendar

I would need a default scroll view to 8AM- 11PM in Day/Week With a fixed Header which includes an option of choosing the Month/Day/Week and the Previous/Next/Today buttons. But the time before 8AM shld be scrollable if the user wishes to see it.

Something similar to what we have in google calendar.

Let me know how i can bring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a post answering the same question : 
https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/issues/828

demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w4urnk?file=index.html

Having an inner scroll for the calendar and reducing the height of the calendar (so that i dont get an outer scroll too )catered to my need.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value using classname and set auto scroll to it:
ie:

```
  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if( document.getElementsByClassName('cal-time') !== undefined &&  document.getElementsByClassName('cal-time').length> 0){
      let scrollbar = document.getElementsByClassName('cal-time')[16];
      scrollbar.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
      scrollbar.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers from @Swati works for me, but instead in the ngDoCheck you should do it in the ngAfterViewInit so that it only gets executed once.

`

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if( document.getElementsByClassName('cal-time') !== undefined &&  document.getElementsByClassName('cal-time').length> 0){
      let scrollbar = document.getElementsByClassName('cal-time')[16];
      scrollbar.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
      scrollbar.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
  }
```

`